# How many numbers are also not multiples of 11?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 1618 numbers between 1 and 10000 that are multiples of 4, 5, or 7, and are also multiples of 3. How many numbers are also not multiples of 11?

I previously asked a question about the first part of the problem, and I'm not sure if I am going about the right way answering the next question. To find the numbers that are also not multiples of 11, would I just subtract 10000/33, 10000/44, 10000/55, and 10000/77 from 1618?

Thank you!

Comment: This, like all previous parts to the problem, will rely on inclusion-exclusion.  You know how many numbers between $1$ and $10000$ are multiples of 3 that are also multiples of at least one of 4,5,7.  Now... you should be able to count how many numbers between $1$ and $10000$ are multiples of $3$ and $11$ who are also multiples of at least one of $4,5,7$.  Counting what you want is the difference of these two counts.

Comment: Rewritten, first count how many numbers between $1$ and $10000$ are multiples of $12,15,$ or $21$.  Subtract from that the number of numbers between $1$ and $10000$ who are multiples of $132$ or $165$ or $231$.

Comment: Have you tried the idea you thought of? When I try it, I get $778$. That is, after eliminating multiples of $11$, less than half of the $1618$ numbers remain. Does the result seem plausible?